# GNU\Linux clustreing , Which level? Which application?

Tags: linux, kernel, cluster, distributed-filesystem

I need to start GNU* clustering, But I have problem, Which level:

- DB level? (replication)
- file system? (distributed)
- process level ? (such as intel fortran for civilization softwares)
- new process ? (such as above with some differnces)

I know DB level have per db backend seperated rrplication. Distrinuted file systems in linux is `btrFS` and freebsd uses `zfs`.But i have serious problem with process clustering and its softwares.

Anyway , Question is, What's kernel level of process level?If I strt it , Do I have to forced to use a distributed fs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cman is new cluster project and redhat says:

> The Red Hat Cluster Suite cluster infrastructure provides the basic functions for a group of computers (called nodes or members) to work together as a cluster. Once a cluster is formed using the cluster infrastructure, you can use other Red Hat Cluster Suite components to suit your clustering needs (for example, setting up a cluster for sharing files on a GFS file system or setting up service failover). The cluster infrastructure performs the following functions:
>       1. Cluster management
>       2. Lock management
>       3. Fencing
>       4. Cluster configuration management 
>   Cluster Management
>   Cluster management manages cluster quorum and cluster membership. CMAN (an abbreviation for cluster manager) performs cluster management in Red Hat Cluster Suite for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5. CMAN is a distributed cluster manager and runs in each cluster node; cluster management is distributed across all nodes in the cluster ( “CMAN/DLM Overview”).
>   CMAN keeps track of cluster quorum by monitoring the count of cluster nodes. If more than half the nodes are active, the cluster has quorum. If half the nodes (or fewer) are active, the cluster does not have quorum, and all cluster activity is stopped. Cluster quorum prevents the occurrence of a "split-brain" condition — a condition where two instances of the same cluster are running. A split-brain condition would allow each cluster instance to access cluster resources without knowledge of the other cluster instance, resulting in corrupted cluster integrity.
>   Quorum is determined by communication of messages among cluster nodes via Ethernet. Optionally, quorum can be determined by a combination of communicating messages via Ethernet and through a quorum disk. For quorum via Ethernet, quorum consists of 50 percent of the node votes plus 1. For quorum via quorum disk, quorum consists of user-specified conditions.
>   CMAN keeps track of membership by monitoring messages from other cluster nodes. When cluster membership changes, the cluster manager notifies the other infrastructure components, which then take appropriate action. For example, if node A joins a cluster and mounts a GFS file system that nodes B and C have already mounted, then an additional journal and lock management is required for node A to use that GFS file system. If a cluster node does not transmit a message within a prescribed amount of time, the cluster manager removes the node from the cluster and communicates to other cluster infrastructure components that the node is not a member. Again, other cluster infrastructure components determine what actions to take upon notification that node is no longer a cluster member. For example, Fencing would fence the node that is no longer a member.
>   ⁠[image]

home page of cman is [here](https://www.sourceware.org/cluster/cman/).